# Custom splash screen not showing

Tags: java, android

I have added a new splash screen just with the company logo for the moment, I have added this where I would imagine everything would go but I still get just a white screen when the app is loading. Any thoughts?

*Styles.xml*

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogDarkBlue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorDarkBlue</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

*launch_screen.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- The android:opacity=”opaque” line — this is critical in preventing a flash of black as your theme transitions. -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>

        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/white_lblue_logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Manifest image[image]

Comment: Any *.Java file contents that you like to share ?

Comment: I don't think there are any, can you think of any helpful ones?

Comment: Share your activity code as well

Comment: Can you share your manifest, where you set the theme "AppTheme.Launcher" on your Activity ?

Comment: Added an image of the manifest

Comment: Where do you reference (i.e. use) the `AppTheme.Launcher` ? e.g as an activity theme

Comment: at the bottom of the first code snippet

Comment: That is where you *define* it, you must then *use* it, usually by setting it as an activity's theme

Comment: But this is intended to be used before the activity has started so not sure how that would work?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/app-splash-screen-with-appcompat-theme.html)